# View level security in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

`/foobar/{id}` is the resourse for all users which gives respective data for users. I want to secure that only authorized user can access that resource. How to authorize it in symfony2 using symfony2 security.

Comment: try http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Answer (score 0):

**[1]**

```
#security.yml
access_control:
    ......
    - { path: ^/foobar/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**[2]**

```
#routing.yml
foobar:
    pattern:   /foobar/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: TestBundle:User:foobar }
```

**[3]**

```
#UserController.php
public function foobarAction($id)
{
    if ($id !== $this->getUser()->getId()) {
        //do something for authentication fail
    }
}
```